# jquery datepicker disable weekends without beforeShowDay

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have integrated the jQuery DatePicker in my homepage. The Problem is that I can't disable weekends with the `beforeShowDay` function because I already use `beforeShowDay` to mark specific dates. I hope there is any possibility to disable weekends without the `beforeShowDay` function.

```js
$(function() {
  var eventDates = {};
  <?php
    for ($i = 0; $i <= sizeof($view) - 1; $i++)
    {
      $date = explode(":" , $view[$i]);
        echo "eventDates[ new Date( '" . $date[1] . "' )] = new Date( '" . $date[1] . "' );";
    }
  ?>

  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    firstDay: 1,
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    maxDate: new Date,
    minDate: "2016-03-08",
    dayNames: ['Sonntag', 'Montag', 'Dienstag', 'Mittwoch', 'Donnerstag', 'Freitag', 'Samstag'],
    dayNamesShort: ['So', 'Mo', 'Di', 'Mi', 'Do', 'Fr', 'Sa'],
    dayNamesMin: ['So', 'Mo', 'Di', 'Mi', 'Do', 'Fr', 'Sa'],
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
      $("#datepicker_value").val(dateText);
      $(this).parent('form').submit();
    },
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
      var highlight = eventDates[date];
      if (highlight) {
        return [true, "eventyellow", ''];
      } else {
        return [true, '', ''];
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still use `beforeShowDay`, you just need to combine your current logic with that to exclude weekends.

Assuming you're using the jQueryUI datepicker then it has a built in method to exclude weekends - `$.datepicker.noWeekends();`. Try this:

```
beforeShowDay: function(date) {
  // exclude weekends
  if (!$.datepicker.noWeekends(date)[0])
    return [false, '', ''];     

  // highlight dates
  return [true, eventDates[date] ? 'eventyellow' : '', ''];
}
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/sucpbhfv/)

Comment: it doesn't work for me.
if i use ur code(Copy&Paste) all dates will be disabled.

Comment: Apologies - I had the logic backwards. I updated the answer and added a working example.